# Yii2 Issue Filtering in Grid using Typehead

Tags: php, yii2, grid, typehead

I'm trying to combine filtering in Kartik Gridview with the Typehead widget.

I'm following the guidlines from [Krajee Article](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/typeahead#advanced-usage), combined with this issue [Github Issue](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid/issues/34).

**This is my code in my index.php**

```
[
    'attribute' => 'type',
    'vAlign' => 'middle',
    'value' => 'type',
    'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_TYPEAHEAD,
    'filterWidgetOptions' => [
        'pluginOptions' => ['highlight' => true],
        'dataset' => [
            [
                'local' => ArrayHelper::map(MasterProduct::find()->orderBy('master_prod_id')->where(['user_id' => $userId])->asArray()->all(), 'type', 'typr'),
                // 'datumTokenizer' => "Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value')",
                'display' => 'value',
                // 'prefetch' => $baseUrl . '/samples/countries.json',
                'remote' => [
                    'url' => Url::to(['/master-product/index']) . '?q=%QUERY',
                    'wildcard' => '%QUERY'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Type..'],
    'width' => '210px',
    'hAlign' => 'center'
],
```

**And this is my code in controller.php**

```
 public function actionIndex($q = null) {
    $model = new MasterProduct();
    $searchModel = new MasterProductSearch();
    $query = new \yii\db\Query();

    $query->select('type')
            ->from('master_product')
            ->where('type LIKE "%' . $q . '%"')
            ->orderBy('type');
    $command = $query->createCommand();
    $data = $command->queryAll();
    $out = [];
    foreach ($data as $d) {
        $out[] = ['value' => $d['type']];
    }
    Json::encode($out);
    $userId = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
    $searchModel->user_id = $userId;
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = 50;

    return $this->render('index', [
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'model' => $model,
                'userId' => $userId,
    ]);
```

The column successfully filters the data, but it doesn't do auto completion/suggestion like the [Demo](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/typeahead#advanced-usage).

Example:
My expectation is like this,
[image]

ie, the user only inputs `sau`, the the Typehead shows all data that contain `sau` and then it uses auto filtering.

But what I get is the inverse of my expectation.

#### How do I can make the Typehead work well?

and anyone can explain what purpose of the 'datumTokenizer' and 'prefetch'  in the file **index.php**?

Answer (score 0):

May u have same id or class on the page, try to comment rendering _search file.

```
<?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>
```